# What does this error mean? - httperf: connection failed with unexpected error 105

Tags: errno, httperf

Does anyone know what this httperf error means? Is this having a negative effect on my tests?

```
httperf: connection failed with unexpected error 105
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The numeric error code is an *errno* value. When errno is 105 (ENOBUFS) it means that there's no buffer space available. Ie, buy more RAM or reduce the maximum size of the buffers for TCP sockets.

To find out what the error code meant, I did:

```
grep 105 /usr/include/*/*errno*
```

which gave me:

```
/usr/include/asm-generic/errno.h:#define    ENOBUFS     105 /* No buffer space available */
```

Also wikipedia might have more details if you look for ENOBUFS.